# Can't receive UDP multicast while VPN is active

Tags: java, udp, netty, vpn

I'm using the ConnectionlessBootstrap to create a UDP socket for multicast in the local network. The channel receives the multicast packets as long as my VPN is not active. Once the VPN is activated the channel no longer receives mutlicast packets. After I closed the VPN connection the channel starts receiving packets again (without restarting).
I create the channel like in the following:

```
DatagramChannel channel;
channel = (DatagramChannel) bootstrap.bind( new InetSocketAddress( localPort ) );
channel.joinGroup( multicastAddress.getAddress() );
```

I thought it might be that netty accidently choose the wrong network interface so I configured it manually in the bootstrap options.

```
NetworkInterface multicastInterface = ...
bootstrap.setOption( "networkInterface", multicastInterface );
```

Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem.
I checked with wireshark whether the packets are actually received on the local interface when the VPN is active - and the packets are still received but don't reach the channel.

*Does someone know how I can receive the multicast packets even while the VPN connection is active?*

Comment: You need a [split-VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling), configuration and availability depending on the VPN and client software.

Comment: Good to know. I'll take a look into later this day.